# Bad syntax for region SIMPLE -- dmextract CIAO 4.15

Tags: data-analysis, chandra

I am trying to perform a radial profile analysis using Chandra's CIAO 4.15 [dmextract](https://cxc.cfa.harvard.edu/ciao/ahelp/dmextract.html) function but keep getting the following error: "bad syntax for region SIMPLE". I cannot find any relevant documentation on the site regarding this issue, and it is not touched on in the [4.15 bugs page](https://cxc.cfa.harvard.edu/ciao/bugs/). Has anyone else run into this issue? If so, have you found a resolution, or can the issue be chalked up to too faint of data?

Comment: The exact function call that leads to the error message might be useful information here.